# FOSUserBundle login form and achitecture of symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an existing database and am using the FosUserBundle to log my users on. I had to add the Salt field to encode the password of my Entities. But in the existing database, the passwords are not encoded! 
How can I encode all the users' passwords I have? Is there any APP/console command to generate the Salt and the encoded passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Mb it's too late, but I think you forgot to choose encoder in app/config/security.yml, if you create user with fosuserbundle register form.

Answer (score 0):

You need create symfony console command,and create method for encode passwords, get all user, in foreach encode each password.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html

Note, you need add in app/config/security.yml next code:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
```